# How to debug in gradle dependency library code

Tags: java, debugging, gradle, testng, cucumber-jvm

I'm trying to run tests using Cucumber, TestNG and gradle (there are no official example in cucumber+testng+gradle and as I understand from gradle github repo there are no current support for this stack of tools)

```
gradle tests --tests com.CR --stacktrace
```

shows that test didn't run with Exception

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.TestExecutionException: No tests found for given includes: [com.CR](--tests filter)
```

where **com.CR** is class with @CucumberOptions

After some investigation I'm found out that something go wrong in cucumber library in class **cucumber.api.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests.class** and I'm trying to debug it.

I'm setting debug point in this class. And run gradle with debug options

```
gradle test --tests com.CR -Dorg.gradle.debug=true --no-daemon
```

After that 'm connecting to remote debug port 5005
But it's not stops on any of my debug points.

---

So the question is how to debug code of dependency library or what I'm doing wrong?

p.s. example of code https://github.com/sirdir/cucumber-testng-gradle

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Without debugging.
There are some additional setting that must be done in gradle test {} task to run testng cucumber-runner class.

Comment: wrote article on medium how to parallel tests in cucumber+gradle+testng https://medium.com/@phddir/gradle-testng-and-paralleling-scenarios-in-cucumber-jvm-a826ac305ff2